# How To Set Up GA4 UTM Tags & Test Them With Thresholding Issues?

Tags: google-analytics, utm-parameters

So I recently downgraded to GA4 from UA. I am trying to set up utm parameters again. They seem easy enough, but the problem is testing them.

When I go to test them, my data is thresholded because Google is trying to prevent individuals from being identified. In this case, they are preventing me from identifying myself as a successful lead. At least so I think. There is also the chance that my utm parameters are wrong. To mitigate against that possibility I have used https://ga-dev-tools.google/campaign-url-builder/. I cannot turn off audiences / data studio as this would stop putting people into our remarketing ads.

How can I test my utm parameters without getting filtered by GA4 thresholding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make a second test ga4 property to fix this**

**Step 1**

Make a new ga4 property
Grab the manual tracking code and place it between two html tags in notepad.

```
<html>
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-EZVKRNVG2B"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'yourtag#');
</script>
</html>
```

Then name that file Test.html and upload it to your website in the public folder.

**Step 2**

Next make a second html document with a hyperlink containing your utm parameters linking to the first page.

```
<html>
<a href="https://www.perfectseowebsites.com/Test.html?utm_source=EmailClick&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=EmailCampaign&utm_id=Email1">Test</a>
</html>
```

Name it Test2.html and drop it into your public folder.

**Step 3**

Now visit your Test2.html page, in my case https://www.perfectseowebsites.com/Test2.html and click the link twice.

Wait 1 day for google analytics to update their data.
Enter GA4 and go to business objectives, to the traffic acquisition sub section. You can now see if your UTM tags were properly attributed.

Answer (score 0):

To accurately analyze UTM parameters in Google Analytics 4 (GA4) without being limited by thresholding, you can follow these strategies.

Utilize a test server or staging environment to control traffic and examine data without threshold limitations.  Monitor real-time reports in GA4 to promptly observe incoming data and confirm proper UTM parameter tracking and event/conversion triggering.  Export raw data to BigQuery (if integrated) to employ data sampling techniques and analyze UTM parameters more accurately, bypassing threshold limitations in GA4. Compare UTM parameter performance between GA4 and previous Universal Analytics (UA) implementations using historical data to identify any discrepancies or tracking setup issues.

Remember to correctly format and append UTM parameters to URLs, ensuring alignment with tracking goals. By implementing these methods, you can effectively test UTM parameters and analyze data without hinderance from GA4 thresholding.

Comment: Did it come from chatgpt ?